# In Scala, what is the running time of trimStart and trimEnd for ListBuffer?

Tags: scala, complexity-theory, scala-collections

Suppose I'm only removing a single element. I would like these methods to implement a fixed size ListBuffer. I would only use if they run in O(1) time. The documentation is slightly ambiguous does anybody know the implementation details?

Comment: Removing from where? Start? End? Index? Arbitrary by element?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The relevant implementation is [there (for `ListBuffer`)](https://lampsvn.epfl.ch/trac/scala/browser/scala/tags/R_2_9_0_1/src//library/scala/collection/mutable/ListBuffer.scala#L1) and [there (for `BufferLike`)](https://lampsvn.epfl.ch/trac/scala/browser/scala/tags/R_2_9_0_1/src//library/scala/collection/mutable/BufferLike.scala#L1).

`trimStart(n)` is linear with respect to `n` (so, constant if you remove a single element); `trimEnd(n)` is linear with respect to the size of the collection.

Apart from that, I fail to see how you want to have a fixed-size `ListBuffer` on which you change the size with such `trim` methods…